# tee: concatenate content of files while processing them individually

Tags: unix, pipe

The objective is to remove the header from each file in a list, and process the files individually using an awk script.

I'm also interested in applying the awk script to the overall content of these files (without headers).

I know I could loop through `head -n +2` to create the overall file, but I'm interested in learning more about `tee` usage to divert data within a pipe.

```
 for f in `ls or_${1}_*.csv`; do
     printf "\n${f}\n"
     echo "-----------------"
     tail -n +2 $f  | awk -f audit_or.awk
 done
```

I've tried combinations of the code below with `tee tmp` (tmp = last file processed), `tee cat - tmp` without success:

```
 rm -f tmp
 touch tmp

 for f in `ls or_${1}_*.csv`; do
     printf "\n${f}\n"
     echo "-----------------"
     tail -n +2 $f  | tee >> tmp | awk -f audit_or.awk
 done

 echo ""
 echo " All files "
 echo " --------- "
 awk -f audit_or.awk tmp
```

Am I on the right track? Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain about job of your script?

Comment: It checks for correct layout and performs data checks (aggregation,count distinct, date ranges etc) for a series of data dump files by time period. Since these files are all loaded downstream from this, I also need to compare overall input to output given the entire data.

Comment: I have a good solution: check summary with new input data instead of writing awk. use `md5sum command`

Comment: I need awk (or python/bash...) to publish the aggregates, counts and ranges in case we want to audit processes upstream. The question isn't about the script itself, but how to divert a pipeline to append data to a file using `tee`.